# How do we get the exceptions handled in python flask code in azure web app logs

Tags: azure, logging, azure-log-analytics

I have a flask app run on azure web app.
For debug purpose, we have print statements in exception handling and other places to check the progress of the code.
However i'm unable to find these print statements in azure logs.

While working on VM it was easier to find the logs on the console.

Note: i have tried with app service logs and diagnostic logs. However i'm not able to find the custom print statement in azure logs.

How do we get logging in azure to have the custom messages in the python flask 
code?

```
try:
    self.asset_name = req_json['assetname']
except KeyError:
    print("Asset Name cannot be empty")
    return "Asset Name cannot be empty"
```

Comment: could you please share some sample code?

Comment: @IvanYang: i have print statement in the exception. i want these in the log files generated by azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a few trying around the azure diagnostic logs, i found that using the logging module of python can be useful. The print statements do occur but not as expected.
So the solution which worked for me:

```
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(format='Custom Logs: %(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

try:
    self.asset_name = req_json['assetname']
except KeyError:
    logger.exception("Asset Name cannot be empty")
    return "Asset Name cannot be empty"
```

These logs can be found in the console logs of the diagnostic logs which we need to turn on in azure.

Comment: Good job! I thought about this, but I just thought you might prefer to use print() method, then I suggested to use the solution in my answer.